# Unable to lookup tf transform

Tags: transforms, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm unable to lookup tf transforms in my C++ node for some reason, unless the parent and child are the same. I have done this many times before and checked with the tutorials and wikis but am not having any luck. The tf tree displays fine in RVIZ as well as command line with the tf_echo. I've tried multiple different rosbags that worked fine in other ROS nodes but nothing is working with this node.

What is different is that this time I am working with a ROS package where there are no classes, everything is in functions but I don't think that should matter because that is how the tutorial is done.

Here is a code snippet:

```
void laserCloudHandler(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr &laserCloudMsg) {
    tf::TransformListener tf_listener;

    if (tf_listener.waitForTransform("world", "velodyne_frame", laserCloudMsg->header.stamp, ros::Duration(0.2))) {

      // Get the tf transform.
      tf::StampedTransform tf_transform;
      tf_listener.lookupTransform(world_frame, velo_frame, laserCloudMsg->header.stamp, tf_transform);
    }

    else
    {
      ROS_FATAL("UNABLE TO LOOKUP INITIAL TRANSFORM!");
    }  
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what may be wrong?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269437/unable-to-lookup-tf-transform/) by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2017-08-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on 2017-08-23**:
@gvdhoorn thanks for fixing that formatting, i couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What is different is that this time I am working with a ROS package where there are no classes, everything is in functions but I don't think that should matter because that is how the tutorial is done.

just a guess, but seeing as you only instantiate your listener in your callback: `0.2` seconds is probably not enough time for the `tf::TransformListener` to see enough of your tree to fill the buffer and be able to retrieve transforms for you. TF needs a buffer, or it can't do anything.

Try instantiating your listener in a scope outside your callbacks (as a global variable fi). I would expect things to improve.

---

Edit: to avoid globals (and possible leakage) you could also use `boost::bind(..)` or use C++11 lambdas / closures.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on 2017-08-23**:
I tried increased time before but it didn't help. I also tried making it a global variable but I get this error:

[FATAL] [1503499756.057001407]: You must call ros::init() before creating the first NodeHandle
Couldn't find an AF_INET address for []

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-23**:
Try doing it after `ros::init(..)` and after you create your first `NodeHandle`.

**Comment by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on 2017-08-23**:
Those are in the main so I wouldn't be able to make it global anymore.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-23**:
Yes; use pointers (ie: `tf::TransformListener* my_listener_`, and then in `main(..)`: `my_listener_ = new tf::TransformListener(..)` or wrap things in `shared_ptr`s).

**Comment by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on 2017-08-23**:
Oh right, thanks that fixed it!